# Omniauth + Devise Error: Could not find hashie-1.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Then I run `bundle update`.  No problem so far. But when I run `rails server` I get this error:

```
Could not find hashie-1.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I thought that bundler was supposed to resolve and satisfy all dependencies, but I tried this anyway:

```
gem install hashie-1.2.0
```

Which gave this:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'hashie-1.2.0' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: hashie-model
```

I'm new to Rails and I feel I'm at a dead end.  Suggestions?

UPDATE:  I also have run `bundle install` (to be exact `bundle install --without production`) several times.  I get the same error when running `rails server` after that.

UPDATE: I aslo tried adding `gem 'hashee'` in the Gemfile before  omniauth-facebook.  No luck.

Comment: UPDATE: When I push up to Heroku it's fine.  I guessing something is corrupt in my environment.  Suggestions how to figure out what?  Here is some basic env info: [Rails 3.2.2 | ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0] | gem 1.8.10 | Bundler version 1.0.22]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  I think it was some problem with bundler.  I did some different things, and I have to admit that I'm not 100% sure what fixed it.  I think what did it was this:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
bundle install mail
```

However, it did not work until my second reinstall I think. Upon the install command, it installed everything, not just mail and its dependencies. The only other thing I did was to delete `/usr/bin/bundler` after the first reinstall.  It did not reappear.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are just using bunder incorrectly.

`bundle update` doesn't resolve new dependencies, it simply looks at the gem manifest, which is stored in `Gemfile.lock` and updates those gems to the most recent gem allow by the constraints placed on them in the `Gemfile`.

Since you are trying to install a new gem, what you what to run is `bundle install` which will make a comparison between your `Gemfile` and your `Gemfile.lock` and install any gems that are not listed in your `Gemfile.lock`.

I think `bundle install` should do the trick for you.

As a side note, bundler tries to make this as easy as possible for you by aliasing `bundle` to `bundle install`.  So, unless you are explicitly looking to update your gems, you can just type `bundle` and get the behavior that you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry I did not provide enough information.  I ran bundle install as well as then bundle update.  I did this multiple times.  Same error.

Comment: ah ok, interesting. Well, in that case, add hashie to your Gemfile before omniauth-facebook.

`gem 'hashie', '~>1.2.0'`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already too, except I used the version number and did it at the end of the file.  In any case, I tried it just like you said, and I still get the error.